# How to create thumbnail of different files?

Tags: plugin-development, thumbnails

I am storing my uploads in a separate folder and using separate table to save the location in database.

I have gone through [WP_Image_Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) , [wp_image_editor_gd](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor_gd/) and [wp_image_editor_imagick](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor_imagick/) .

I also tried [wp_insert_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and [wp_generate_attachment_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata)

Is there any way to create thumbnails for PDF, video, doc, RAR, and ZIP using these classes or any other classes / functions in wordpress ?

Please let me know, if I should provide more detail on it or any question you want me to answer to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're already looking in the right places. (And nowadays WordPress [already supports PDF thumbnails through ImageMagick](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/15/enhanced-pdf-support-4-7/) - [code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.2/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php#L149).)

To add a new thumbnail generator, you'll need to:

- write a new [WP_Image_Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) class that supports the file type or types you want - you'll want to extend the base class and override at least

  - test()
  - load()
  - supports_mime_type() - to match the content types of the files you want to preview
  - multi_resize() - this is the method called to generate thumbnails
- hook the [wp_image_editors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_image_editors/) filter, and in the hook implementation include your editor class (if you haven't already) and add the class name to the filtered list, with whatever priority you want.